# Identifying Mongoose schema validation errors as HTTP status codes

Tags: keystonejs

I'm leveraging Keystone.js to provide a lightweight CMS and API. I'm checking for duplicate entries on a List as such:

```
Registration.schema.post('save', function(error, registration, next) {
  if (error && error.name === 'MongoError' && error.code === 11000) {
    error = Error(`409|${ registration['email'] } is already registered`);
  }

  next(error);
});
```

I'm parsing the status code off the error message to return in my API endpoint.

Is there a different way to provide a friendly error message for duplicates in Keystone admin and be able to return the correct status code for API calls?

Comment: Is your currently-implemented message not friendly enough?

Comment: It works, but not as cleanly as I would like.

Comment: @Brandon I post an example to you.

Comment: Thanks @FrancisRodrigues. I'll try to check it out soon.

Answer (score 0):

#### as db version v3.6.9

```
$ mongod --version
db version v3.6.9
git version: 167861a164723168adfaaa866f310cb94010428f
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: debian81
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

I think you should check for `ValidationError` property instead `MongoError` as below:

```
RegistrationSchema.create(obj)
  .then(...)
  .catch(err => console.error('[registration] output: ', err);
```

We'll suppose the `email` is not mentioned before to simulate an `is required` error.

You'll see like that:

```
[registration] error:  { ValidationError: Registration validation failed: email: Path `email` is required.
at ValidationError.inspect (....)
errors: 
 {
   email:
     { Path `email` is required.
      ...
      message: 'Path `email` is required.',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        properties: [Object],
        kind: 'required',
        path: 'email',
        value: [],
        reason: undefined,
        '$isValidatorError': true } },
  _message: 'Registration validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError' }
```